# using linq to create more values?

Tags: .net, linq

I have a `IEnumerable<int>` which I can print out and which I can double (code below). That's not a problem. How do I adjust the linq statement so it will take these 3 values and output 6 values? For example have the values double and half so the values would be `12, 3, 16, 4, 8, 2`.

```
foreach (var v in (new int[] { 6, 8, 4 }).Select(s=>s*2))
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (var v in (new[] { 6, 8, 4 }).SelectMany(s => new[] { s * 2, s / 2 }))
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```